# Easy form-to-email in site.com?

Tags: site.com

Is there an easy way to create a form-to-email in site.com? I just want a form that, when completed, sends an email to a set address.

I can create forms, of course, that are tightly bound to a salesforce object. But if I want a quick, light way to have salesforce send an email with text from the form, what are my options?

I'd rather not create an object to handle this, or even tweak workflow rules to add email sending.

Comment: Do you have web to lead in your org that you could enable?

Comment: Yes, we have to web to lead. But we don't want to create a lead here, just an email.

Comment: Was thinking that while you don't want to tweak workflow, you could very easily use a web to lead form to generate the email you desire or have the form kick off a custom mail services controller when it comes in.